# Dynamic Trait NoSuchFieldError @2.9.0RC4

Tags: scala

Is the following a bug or on purpose?

```
trait Dyn {
  val D1 = new Dynamic {
    def applyDynamic(name: String)(args: Any*) = "Hi"
  }
  object D2 extends Dynamic {
    def applyDynamic(name: String)(args: Any*) = "Hey"
  }
}
trait T { self: Dyn =>
  def foo1 = D1.X
  def foo2 = D2.X
}
object T extends T with Dyn
object Dyn extends Dyn

T.D1.X // works
Dyn.D1.X  // works
T.foo1 // doesn't work: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: reflPoly$Cache1

T.D2.X // works
Dyn.D2.X  // works
T.foo2 // works
```

Comment: it looks like a bug, you should ask the scala mailing list.

Comment: odersky fixed it 3mins ago [24922](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/24922)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably another instance of bug [#4560](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4560)